# How to get language by region

Tags: java, android

I need to get the language of a region or address.

Right now I know the address is in the United Kingdom so with the method below I get Welsh since wales is also in the United Kingdom and has its own language cy_GB

However the address is in London where the language is English en_GB

```
language = getLocale("United Kingdom");

private Locale getLocale(String country) {
        for (Locale locale:Locale.getAvailableLocales()) {
            if(locale.getDisplayCountry().equalsIgnoreCase(country)){ // finds welsh first
                return locale;
            }
        }
..
```

How can I get address of a region or address?Is there any android or java api that I can use

Comment: No way to get the language from country alone. It is quite common that there are more than one language in a given country.

Comment: I think what you need is out of scope of a programming language or API. What you need is an external web service or database if you want to embed data in your application.